# Best Data Model for Unique Data Selection and Assignment in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, datastax, denormalization, nosql

What's the best Cassandra data model and query for the following situation?

Our system is responsible for uniquely assigning serial numbers to our toasters, when each one is created at our factory.

- We have multiple models of toasters, each type uniquly identified by a different UPC.
- A serial number can *never* be assigned to more then one toaster model (UPC specific).
- It's not crucial to assign serial numbers in order.
- At least once a day, we need to find out how many un-assigned serial numbers we still have for each UPC.
- Our system is supplied by serial numbers from time to time by another system in large batches by their UPC.

Performance Requirements:

- Finding an un-assigned serial number for a UPC *must be fast*.
- Inserting new serial numbers does *not* need to be fast.
- Counting does *not* need to be fast.

Our dataset is about 10M serial numbers today growing about 1M annually.

We are currently using Cassandra 2.0.x and will soon migrate to 2.1.x.

Comment: Some clarifying questions: What is the format of the UPC? How many unique UPCs do you have?

Comment: We have about 50 currently, with expected growth of about 10-20 per year. The format is the UPCs are actually UUIDs - I called them UPCs because I thought it would be easier to understand.

Comment: I have to say. This sounds like a very small amount of data. What is your primary motivation for using Cassandra? Is it uptime or multiple data centers?

Comment: It's actually part of a larger system, of which other aspects benefit from Cassandra's features. Our goal is to migrate all parts of this system to Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I put a bit of thought behind this one.  There are a couple things that are tricky about this scenario:

- Serial numbers come in, and are assigned (but not right away).  With growth of 1 million per year, that works out to ~2800 new serial numbers per day.  Queuing those up (upserting them when they come in and deleting them when they are assigned) will create a lot of tombstones (essentially 2800 per day).
- With 50 UPCs relating to 10 million serial numbers, that works out to 200k serial numbers per UPC (assuming even distribution).  This means that we can't store the UPC-to-serial numbers relationship in a collection (max size of 65536 items).

I assume that you'll want to be able to figure out which serial numbers are tied to which models, and which models have which serial numbers.  For that, I'd go with two lookup tables:

```
CREATE TABLE serialNumbersByUPC (
  modelUPC uuid,
  insertTime timeuuid,
  serialNumber text,
  PRIMARY KEY (modelUPC,insertTime))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertTime DESC);

CREATE TABLE UPCsBySerialNumbers (
  modelUPC uuid
  insertTime timeuuid,
  serialNumber text,
  PRIMARY KEY (serialNumber));
```

Note that you could also key `serialNumbersByUPC` with `serialNumber` as a clustering key (instead of `insertTime`).  But timeuuids are unique (so there won't be collisions on `serialNumbers`), and clustering by `insertTime` has the added benefit of allowing you to sort by date/time.  Of course, you'll want to make sure that you upsert to both of those tables when assigning a serial number to a UPC.

For the unassigned serial numbers, it might be best to use a queuing system like [HornetQ](http://hornetq.jboss.org/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).  That way you could just pull the new serial numbers off of the queue, and assign them as-needed.  The reason I suggest this, is that using Cassandra to queue-up transient data has been identified as an anti-pattern.

Of course you could decide not to heed the above warning, and insist on using Cassandra for that functionality.  If so, then *this* is how I would store unassigned serial numbers in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE unassignedSerialNumbers (
  dateBucket bigint,
  serialNumber text,
  insertTime timeuuid,
  PRIMARY KEY ((dateBucket),insertTime))
WITH compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400;
```

A few things about this solution:

- I'm partitioning on `datebucket` as I'm not sure how fast you assign the 2800 serial numbers that come in each day.  It's possible that you may want to query just the numbers that came in today, or yesterday.  I've created it as a `bigint`, but you can use whatever size bucket you wish (ex: "20150416" would partition serial numbers that came-in on April 16th, 2015 together).
- If you find that you assign serial numbers fast enough that you don't need to partition by `datebucket`, then I wouldn't worry about that table getting big enough to hinder query performance.  Sure, your deletes will create tombstones that you query will have to contend with, but that should be helped with my last two points.
- I'm clustering on `insertTime` for the same reason as I did in the `serialNumbersByUPC` table.
- I'm using the `DateTieredCompactionStrategy` for this table.  This strategy will keep rows written at the same time in the same SSTABLE files on-disk.  This becomes important for performance as you delete and write new data.
- `gc_grace_seconds` is being set to 1 day instead of 10.  This will force tombstoned rows to be garbage-collected every day.  The drawback of this setting, is that if you have a node go down you need to bring it back within 1 day of it going down to pick-up the deletes.  If you don't you'll need to run a full repair or risk your deleted serial numbers "coming back from the dead."

You'll also want to read up on the [DateTieredCompactionStrategy](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy).  There may be some other options with it that might make sense for you to set.

Let me know if you have any questions, or if I missed anything.

Comment: Setting gc_grace_seconds to 1 day is dangerous since the OP emphasized that a serial number must never be assigned twice.  The churn rate on this application is extremely low (2800 assignments per day), so tombstone buildup should not be a concern.  I'd keep grace seconds at 10 days.  If the churn rate were 2800 per second, then I'd worry about tombstones, but per day it's tiny.

Comment: @jimmeyer Good call.  The OP should probably monitor tombstones before changing something like that.  But with a queue-like table and tombstones hanging around for 10 days, you could potentially have a tombstone to live row ratio of 9:1...and that is concerning.

Comment: How are you calculating 9:1?  If we have 1M unassigned, and 2800 x 10 days of tombstones, then less than 3% of the data would be tombstones.

Comment: @JimMeyer That's true if we have all 1M for the year right away.  The OP mentioned getting serial numbers "from time to time by another system in large batches."  Of course, without knowing what that timeframe is, or how large the batches are, I was thinking in terms of a worst-case scenario.  That would be getting 2800 each day, and potentially having them assigned and deleted before the day's end.  By the beginning of day 10, there could be only 2800 rows in the table and up to 25200 tombstones.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, but in absolute terms I would still consider that a trivial number of tombstones.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Have one table containing un-assigned serial numbers, call it "unassigned".  When you are supplied with new serial numbers they are inserted into "unassigned".  The UPC number would be the partition key and the serial number could be a clustering column.

Then have another table called "assigned".  When you build a toaster, you randomly grab a serial number from the unassigned table and try to insert it into the assigned table using the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause on the insert.  This makes sure that a serial number is only assigned once in case you have multiple processes running.

If the insert is successful, your process goes back and deletes the serial number from the unassigned table.  If the insert fails due to the number already being there, you randomly pick a different number and try that one until you get one that succeeds.

To grab a serial number to try for the insert you could do something like a select from the appropriate unassigned UPC partition with a limit 100, and then randomly pick one of the serial numbers you get back (this is so that if you have multiple processes, they won't all try the same number on the insert attempt).  And limit 100 within a partition will be very fast.

Now to get a count of unassigned numbers, you could do a select count(*) for each UPC partition in the unassigned table, but if you have too many rows, that might timeout.  So you could have a third table with counter columns and just increment and decrement those as serial numbers are added and used.